# android listview layout 3-d affect boxes/tiles

Tags: android, view, android-listview

Can somebody tell me `xml` layout code for attached `image listview`. Note the boxes are having a bit of 3-D tile affect at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: first try at least something, we can just help. But can not code for you.

Comment: @praveenSharma Your question is not clear, where do you want to use listview and for what propose? Also there is no such thing image listview, just listview with what ever views you wish.

Comment: @Babibu its not my question.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your talking about styling your List as a Card layout with the 3D solid at the bottom.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
 <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle">
 <corners android:radius="2dp">
 <solid android:color="#ccc">
 </solid></corners></shape>
 </item>

<item android:bottom="2dp">
<shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle">

<corners android:radius="2dp">

<solid android:color="@android:color/white">

<padding android:bottom="8dp" android:left="8dp" android:right="8dp" android:top="8dp">
</padding></solid></corners></shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

That should do it. For more details have a look at my blog here :

Link : [Card UI](http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-card-layout.html)